# Jquery onmouseover for asp.net web form gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I made a gridview like the following :

```
   <asp:GridView runat="server" id="grvCommandes" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle-CssClass="row_dd"  BackColor="#bbddff"  Font-Names="Verdana" BorderWidth="3px" OnRowDeleting="btnSupprimer_click" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" EmptyDataText="Cette requête ne retourne aucune ligne..." Width="1600px">
    <Columns>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="NO_COMM" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Code Comm."/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="NO_DA" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="No de D.A."/>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitAdm" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Un. Adm."/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE_ART" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Code d'Article"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="desc_abr" ItemStyle-Width="390px" HeaderText="Description"/>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideIT">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="hideIT"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="hideIT" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="dataDiv" data-desc="<%# Eval("DESC_ART") %>"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Crea" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Création"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Recep" ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Émission"/>


           <asp:BoundField DataField="QTE_COMM" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Qtée Comm."  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="QTE_REC" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Qtée Reçu"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="QTE_INV_ACH" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Qtée Ach."  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="QTE_INV_INV" ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Qtée Inv."  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>


    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I wanted a "on mouse over" event, because within the gridview is a short description, it would be convinient if the full descripion was shown when the mouse is over the line.

So googled that and  : http://codepedia.info/gridview-row-mouseover-show-detail-data-in-floating-div-asp-net-c-jquery/

added this thing up in the script along with the required CSS :

```
<script>

    $(".row_dd").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var self = $(this).find(".dataDiv");
        var DESC_ART = self.attr("data-desc");


        $("#dd_desc").html(DESC_ART);


        var x_value = e.pageX;
        var y_value = e.pageY;
        $("#detailedData").css({
            "top": y_value,
            "left": x_value
        }).show();
    });

    $(".row_dd").on("mouseleave", function (e) {
        $("#detailedData").hide();
    });


</script>
```

and i added in the bottom of the page :

```
<div id="detailedData" style="display: none;">
  <dl> 
    <dt>DESC_ART: </dt> <dd id="dd_desc"></dd>

  </dl>
</div>
```

Now i don't know why, the line that has the mouse over becomes withe as expected, but the div dosen't show up. I can't tell what is what with this JQuery code...

EDIT :

added these to my project  :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

but i still can't see to whole description from my database when the mouse is over...

Comment: Looking your code, it should work. Are you getting any client side error in browser console?

Comment: When you say that the div doesn't show up, which one do you mean? The one inside your GridView (class .dataDiv) or the one at the bottom of your page (id detailedData)? I tried your code and it works perfectly, but the `<div>` inside your GridView has no content, so it's going to show up blank. Try `<div class="dataDiv" data-desc="<%# Eval("DESC_ART") %>">Hover Here!</div>`

Comment: @Antoine : Pls check your browser console is there any error ? and make sure jquery library is included in your webpage.

Comment: What does `Eval("DESC_ART")` evaluate to? Does your code work if you replace it with a hard-coded value (e.g. `data-desc="TEST"`)?

Comment: @Satindersingh yeah i don't remanber including jquery anyware... i'm going to check that

Comment: No... dosen't change anything

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin I mean, there is supposed to be a long text in an interactive box when mouse is over the line, it does not happen, the line turn white but the long description does not show appear as it should. my DESC_ART comes from a database...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Strange, the description appears for me using the same code. What I meant by referring to the DESC_ART value was, what kind of values are getting added to your page? In other words, if you viewed source, is the `data-desc` attribute getting populated with a bunch of stuff that might be causing your HTML to break? By replacing it temporarily with a simple hard-coded value, you could rule that out.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function does that ring a bell to you ?

Comment: You might be using an old version of jQuery. Looking at your script tags, you seem to be loading two (old) versions of jQuery which could be conflicting and incompatible with `.on`. Current version is 3.1.1. See https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help everyone... i don't know if i like JQuery that much, i ended up using the asp.net style tooltip  :

```
    protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;
        e.Row.ToolTip = ((CommandeETDA)e.Row.DataItem).DESC_ART;
    }
```

Not too convinient but at least it work for now